# What is the best way to achieve an animate({height}) effect in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve an animation effect in jQuery where I have a box with a height of 0px and a width of 50px. I can use `animate({height :+50, 200})` to get the box to scale (from bottom to up) but I can't then get the bottom bit to go to the top.

**Edit: I got it working see below code:**

CSS

```
.logos, .logosb{    
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:0px;
    bottom: 600px;

}
.logos{
    background: red;
}

.logosb{
    background: #15181f;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

and jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".logo").on('mouseover', function(){

    jQuery(".logos").animate({height: +50}, 2000);
    jQuery(".logos").promise().done(function(){
      jQuery(".logosb").animate({height: +50}, 2000);
    })

  });
});
```

and HTML:

```
<li class=logos><li class=logosb></li></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put relative father with **overflow:hidden** and move the div inside from bottom to top.

edit:
And if want to make an animation start after another, you can use the callback of the animate method.

Here's an example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".relative").on('mouseover', function(){

    jQuery(".logos").stop().animate({top: 0}, 2000,function() {
       // Animation complete.
        jQuery(".logos").stop().animate({top: -50}, 2000);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.relative {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.logos {
  background: blue; 
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:-50px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="relative">
  <div class="logos">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm wondering... this is not the result I want. I want the box to go from 0px to 50px  (x to y) then 50px to 0 (y to z). I don't want the box to com down, but go up...(as it were)

Comment: I edited the answer, see if that's what you expecting.

Comment: I changed again to start on the top.

Comment: Figured it out using, promise()..done() in jQuery and z-index:1000 in CSS (I played one animation on top of the other.When the first has finished the second played on top). Thanks tho you gave me some ideas...

Comment: Came across a problem... if I use position:absolute; bottom: 600px; the position is likely to change on different resolution screens... any idea how to overcome this??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try hover function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#banner-message").hover( function(){

    jQuery(".logos").animate({height: +50}, 2000);
  },
  function(){

    jQuery(".logos").animate({height: -50}, 2000);
  });
});
```

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gybroz5m/1/)